# NodeJS Buffer - ASCII Binary Representation

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, binary, ascii

`number` has `num.toString(2)`

I'm wondering if there's a way to take a string such as `'Hello world'` and convert it to its ASCII binary representation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could utilize the [`charCodeAt()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

First split the string, then map the characters to their respective character code using the [`charCodeAt` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). From there, you can use `.toString(2)` to convert the integer to binary and the [`padStart()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to add leading zero padding.

```
'Hello world'.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt().toString(2).padStart(8, '0')).join(' ');
```

Result:

```
"01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: This works because the characters that ASCII has in common with Unicode (the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block) have single UTF-16 code units and those code units (16 bits) have the same values as in ASCII (8 bits). Without that chain of reasoning, the code is voodoo. See [`charCodeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), as linked in the answer.